# How can I redirect directory using htaccess for specific domain?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have an url like this `example.eu/blog`, but I want to redirect it to `example.com/blog`, it must work only for specific domain `example.eu` because `example.com` points to the same server and redirecting all domains would cause infinite loop. Now I have this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.eu/blog$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/blog/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

I expect it to to redirect blog directory to `example.com/blog` but that rule is never met. I'm testing it here:

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=9953c394-b95b-5e41-8986-9424cae092fe

I googled but all examples didn't include full domain name or didn't include directory name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP_HOST is the "target host" of the request. It does not contain the request URL, i.e. `/blog`

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.eu$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/blog/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

If you already have taken take of the www you can remove the OR and the scond HTTP_HOST condition.

Comment: Yes that's what I needed! Thank you very much, this is a correct answer.